# Jquery dialog with scroll on space bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We know that, the default functionality of a space bar in browser is to scroll to down if no input is active. similarly shift+space bar scroll top.

In my app, I'm using Jquery dialog on which if I press space bar when no input is active the background is scrolled instead of the dialog.

So, I added `tabIndex = -1` which works fine when the dialog height is big (Means when the dialog has a scrollbar). But it is not working when the dialog has no scrollbar (Only the background is scrolling)

```
<div id="contactContainer" class="default-dialog" tabindex="-1"></div>
```

I don't want the user to prevent the space bar typing when no input is active. The scrolling should work normal as I press the space bar. If there is no scrollbar on the dialog, nothing should happen if I press the space bar.

Is anybody faced the same situation? Please give me a suggestion

Comment: Could you please provide a `fiddle` or `snippet` on `dialog` you have now, so that we find a work around for you?

Comment: Sure. Will provide.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, I've a container class which has some overflow elements. I did the following before I open the dialog

```
$('body, .container').addClass('overflow-hidden');
```

and I removed the class in the onClose event of the dialog

CSS:

```
.overflow-hidden { overflow: hidden}
```